# How to Show the List of Videos on the Embedded Youtube Playlist?

Tags: video, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I simply want to embed a Youtube playlist in my website while allowing the users to pick which video from the playlist they want to view. (Showing the playlist button)

**Trial #1:**

```
<iframe width="1280" height="720" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/WanDvtvv_xY?version=3&showinfo=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

**Trial #2:**

```
<iframe width="1280" height="720" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/WanDvtvv_xY" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

**Trial #3:**

```
<iframe width="1280" height="720" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/WanDvtvv_xY?showinfo=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

None of the above code seems to work.

Answer (score -2):

The Solution goes as follows:

`list=[List ID]` must be added to the embed code.